# Performance of 'extract by mask' tool in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, performance, extract-by-mask

Context: A large raster is clipped to create a bunch of smaller rasters based on a bunch of shapefiles.

I've used st_clip() which seems to take forever looping through the different shapefiles, so I've switched to the much faster (but fast enough?) combination of  'where st_intersects()' and smaller tile sizes.

The Extract by Mask tool on arcgis seems to be faster. 
Is there a difference in how they are both done?

As I understand it, it rasterizes the vector shapefile and creates a matrix of 0s and 1s and extracts the values from the base raster which intersect with the 1s.

Comment: It is a good question, but likely hard to answer, except by someone with knowledge of the ArcGIS source code.